# Keeping the nVidia CUDA driver in sync with kernel updates

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, cuda

Does anybody know if it's possible to automatically reinstall the nVidia CUDA driver on kernel updates? As of know I need to switch to a console and run the driver installer manually on kernel updates, so it would be great if it was possible to keep it in sync in the same fashion as the regular proprietary drivers.

I guess I could hack together a script that checks if the module is loaded and runs the installer if not, but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I don't really know what I'm talking about, but I have a hunch your solution will be to leverage [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS) to automatically reinstall the driver when necessary. [This blog post](http://www.giuseppecoviello.net/2010/02/using-nvidia-drivers-on-fedora-12-with-dkms/) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: curious, what is the cuda driver for linux.  I tried to look it up, but it looks like cuda is just part of the latest drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't run nvidia drivers from their site for a while, but when I did this helped [Automatically update manually installed NVidia drivers after kernel updates](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=835573)

Don't know if it still works.